# Angular Mi variable no se actualiza cuando se modifica en el Servicio

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo un `Service` en **Angular** con una variable que se modifica cuando el usuario hace ciertas acciones. Desde el `Componente` de una de mis vistas, tengo una variable que quiero que tenga siempre el valor de la variable del `Servicio`. El problema, es que cuando se modifica la variable del `Servicio`, mi variable en el `Controlador` de la vista **no se modifica**.

**Clase del controlador de la vista:**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  presupuesto:number; // Variable a mantener actualizada

  constructor(private presupuestosService:PresupuestosService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.presupuesto = this.presupuestosService.presupuesto; // Empieza con un 0
    this.mostrarPresupuesto(); // Cargar función para ver realizar pruebas
  }

  mostrarPresupuesto() {
    setTimeout(() => {

      // Este log imprime todo el rato 0, aunque se modifique el servicio (valor inicial de la variable)
      console.log(this.presupuesto);

      // Imprime 0 y cuando la variable del servicio se modifica se ve reflejado (porque es la variable directa)
      console.log(this.presupuestosService.presupuesto);
      this.mostrarPresupuesto();
    },1000);
  }

}
```

No he compartido el código de la clase porque ya indico que la variable del Servicio es accesible y se modifica cuando toca, mientras la otra reserva su valor adquirido en ngOnInit().

Estoy inyectando correctamente el servicio desde @NgModule > Providers: [PresupuestosService], y también lo importo en la clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el servicio puedes crear un EventEmitter:

```
export class PresupuestosService {

  presupuesto = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor(){

   setInterval(()=>{
    let valor = 0;
    // emite un nuevo valor que llegará a los observadores
     this.presupuesto.emit(valor++);

   },1000);

  }
```

Y en el componente se hace una suscripción:

```
constructor(private servicio:PresupuestosService){

    servicio.presupuesto.subscribe(d => {
      // cada vez que el servicio emite un valor se actualiza
      // la variable presupuesto
      this.presupuesto = d;

    });

  }
```

De esa forma cuando el servicio emita un valor el componente lo tendrá actualizado.

Comment: Que sad no haber conocido antes esto, yo usaba behaviorSubject para poder hacer esto mismo :c